# Convert string to array issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate some data for a bar chart in javacript.
This is my code:

```
var barChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : ['0','0','0','9','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
                },
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.8)",
                    highlightFill : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.75)",
                    highlightStroke : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                    data : ['0','0','0','0','14','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
                }
            ]

        };
```

I have 2 variables:

```
first_column_data = "'0','0','0','9','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'";
```

and

```
second_column_data = "'0','0','0','0','14','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'";
```

This variables are dynamically generated. My problem is that if i change the value in **data** from **barChartData** like this:

```
data : [first_column_data]
```

It does not work. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, `first_column_data` is a string, but you need to split the string into an array:

```
 data : first_column_data.split(",")
```

If you need to strip the quotes, do it this way:

```
 data : first_column_data.replace(/'/g, '').split(",")
```

Comment: This will keep the quotes, he probably doesn't want that

Comment: @KarelBílek Based on his sample code, it looks like he does.

Comment: @KarelBílek I have added a version that will strip the quotes.

Comment: His original code will not have the quotes in the array. `['1', '2', '3']` will create an array with strings `1`, `2` and `3` (without the quotes).

Comment: @KarelBílek But his original code does have the quotes. I'm not saying it's correct - I don't know if it is. He asked how to use the string in the same way he currently uses the array, which is what my answer will do.

Comment: @KarelBílek To be clear, I understand that the first code block in my answer creates an array of strings, but that's exactly what OP has in his example.

Answer (score -1):

Try `data : first_column_data`

The notation you are using is for selecting an index.  This would get you the first item in your array: `data : first_column_data[0]`